# How to add numbers into rateyo stars?

Tags: jquery, rateyo

I am using [rateYo](http://rateyo.fundoocode.ninja/) jquery plugin and i want to make star rating for my site. I am trying to add numbers into star shapes like `1 2 3 4 5 6 ....` So i used jquery each function:

```
$(".jq-ry-rated-group path").each(function(i) {
    $(this).html('<span>' + ++i + '</span>');
});
```

But numbers not showing.

Here is rateYo args:

```
$(".rate").rateYo({
  starWidth: '30px',
  numStars: 10,
  halfStar: true,
  rating: 1.5,
  maxValue: 10,
  spacing: '5px',
  starSvg: '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M19 2c1.654 0 3 1.346 3 3v14c0 1.654-1.346 3-3 3h-14c-1.654 0-3-1.346-3-3v-14c0-1.654 1.346-3 3-3h14zm0-2h-14c-2.762 0-5 2.239-5 5v14c0 2.761 2.238 5 5 5h14c2.762 0 5-2.239 5-5v-14c0-2.761-2.238-5-5-5z"/></svg>'
}).on("rateyo.change", function(e, data) {

  var rating = data.rating;
  $('.rated').text(rating);
});
```

And here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z2v4cnwu/)

I am trying to make this:
[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chebX.png)

Comment: Trying to append a `span` to a `path` makes very little sense.

Comment: I did. But not showing again.

Comment: Trying to insert any HTML into the SVG makes little sense, I think. I would maybe rather try to modify the base SVG, so that it includes a `<text></text>` element, and then set the text content of that element via JavaScript after the whole thing is initialized.

Comment: When trying modify svg, rateYo not works good. Can you try and show in my fiddle?